# How to create dynamic link when share button is clicked in android with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to share user posts with dynamic link so that when anyone clicks the link it opens the app with that post's detail. But I am unable to find any good tutorial. Can anyone help me to create this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a service to identify users posts and give each post a unique ID. Then you can handle custom link and retrieve the post ID and request your server for post details. See https://developer.android.com/training/app-links